# .exe files are not registered in Windows Control Panel Add/Remove Programs entry

Tags: windows, pyinstaller

I am a developer who is using Microsoft Windows.

I created and executed a .exe file using pyinstaller, but I cannot confirm that it is installed in the Add/Remove Programs entry in the Windows control panel.

1. Is the .exe file created with pyinstaller not registered in the Add/Remove Programs entry in the Windows Control Panel?
2. How do I get a pyinstaller-generated .exe file to be registered in the Add/Remove Programs item in the Windows Control Panel?

Comment: EXE's those are installed only gets registered in Add/Remove Programs item in control panel. EXE generated using pyinstaller need not to be executed they run directly without any installations.

Comment: Item 2 in [the faq](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ), pyinstaller is not an installer.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.pyinstaller.org/

> PyInstaller freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone
> executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and
> AIX.

That means it creates an exe file from python code.

In Windows to display an application in the Add/Remove programs the application needs to be registered in the OS.
This is usually done by installers.

To achieve your goal please use an installer creator tool such as [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)](https://nsis.sourceforge.io).